# Export compressed in runtime .FLV from AS3 application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flv

Id like to ask if its possible to record ( create from images ) , compress and export to bytes FLV movie from swf in browser (not AIR/EXE) .

I expect that there is way to do it using server , but this will generate lot of traffic .

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

[See this library](http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/simpleflvwriteras-as3-class-to-create-flvs/) by Lee Felarca

Comment: I saw , but You can read that there is no compression and no audio .

Comment: Well there is the only choice now. You can dig into FLV spewcification (http://download.macromedia.com/f4v/video_file_format_spec_v10_1.pdf) and add sound functionality yourself :)

Comment: yeah , but Ill still need compression ... Im looking for more native way to do this .